# How to correctly implement - (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow when trying to retrieve which table cell is selected

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates

I have a delegate for my table view, and would like to be able to trigger an action when the user selects a cell in the tableview.

How is the method - (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow correctly implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the table delegates set up properly (see Apple's `AdvancedTableViewCells` tutorial or any number of good tutorials out there for more info), then you follow Apple's protocol by implementing this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   

    // in here you can do stuff based on which cell they selected
    // at a certain index path, like the examples below

    // get value for which row was pressed
    int row = indexPath.row;

    // or find cell that was just pressed and grab handle for the new info that needs to be put on it
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *newButton;
    newButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:4];

    UILabel *newLabel;
    newLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];

    // or de-select the row per Apple's Human Interface Guidelines 
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Those are just generic examples, but hopefully they shed a little light on the subject for you!